# How to make axios's API requests reusable with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, axios

How can I make **axios's** API requests **reusable** through my app, 
so I can avoid writing writing the same code over and over again..

```
//load the axios HTTP library
window.axios = require('axios');
window.Vue = require('vue');


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted(){
        console.log('hello!');
    }
});
```

I was thinking of trying something like this ( **[gist](https://gist.github.com/d-levin/ce791d7f9328d00f41abff32fd0ec63a)** ) but I don't know how can I attach the functions to **Vue instance** and call these functions from **vue-components directly** ..

Comment: I've built [_axios-resource_](https://emileber.github.io/axios-resource/#/) which helps wrap common calls with a simple API.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject axios as Vue property :
`Vue.prototype.$http = require('axios');`
Then you can use it like that : `this.$http.get(...)`
Or you can checkout this [repository](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios)